# std::vector<int> allocated with (n,0) is not iterable

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


void monitor_vector(std::vector<int> myV)
{
  std::vector<int>::iterator it = myV.begin();
  std::cout << "Vector size: " << myV.size() << std::endl;
  while (*it)
  {
    std::cout << "Element " << it-myV.begin() << ": " << *it << std::endl;
    it++;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> myVector(4,1);
  monitor_vector(myVector);
  return 0;
}
```

Basically, I create a `std::vector<int>` that has `4` elements, and assign each element `1`. When I execute this code, all is well. The output shows each element.

However, when I execute it with this line

```
  std::vector<int> myVector(4,1);
```

replaced by this line:

```
  std::vector<int> myVector(4,0);
```

I can't see any output. The output is:

```
yilmazali@yilmazali:~/cpp_practice$ g++ -o la vector_practice.cpp
yilmazali@yilmazali:~/cpp_practice$ ./la
Vector size: 4
yilmazali@yilmazali:~/cpp_practice$
```

Why does it ignore the elements with default integer value? Still, they are there as the member of `std::vector`.

Thanks for your time, 
Ali

Comment: is it because while loop sees `*it` as 0 and refuses to iterate?

Comment: Yes, 0 is false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You iterate `while (*it)`.

If you fill your vector with zeros, `*it == 0` and therefore `if (*it)` is like `if (false)`: the loop body is never executed.

Instead, loop while `it != myV.end()`

Comment: thats right, thanks! I guess thats the way to go for vector iterations.

Comment: @AliYılmaz -- re: "I guess thats the way to go for vector iterations" -- that's the way to go for **all** container iterations (unless there's a specific reason to do it differently). That's one of the fundamental notions of the STL (e.g., Standard Template Library, which was added to the C++ standard library). Sequences are designated by a pair of iterators, and you iterate through a sequence by incrementing the first iterator until it's equal to the second.

Comment: I'd say the way to go, nowadays, is [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)